# Python: How to deal with replacement character �

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading a csv file and encountering a problem `'invalid continuation byte'), errno is utf-8` it's happening when it gets to a line with a name `Maga�a` which is supposed to be `Magaña`*(If I open the csv file in Atom (my editor) and have it auto detect the encoding it chooses `Windows 1252` and converts the `�` to `ñ`)*

My question is how do I convert `�` to `ñ` when opening or reading the file for insert into a db?

I've tried this as a test:

```
print 'Maga�a'.decode('windows-1252').encode('utf-8')
```

which prints `Magaï¿½a`

Example code:

```
reader = open("my_csv.txt", "r")
for csv_row in reader:
  # insert_row_sql = 'INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,.... )'
  csv_values = csv_row.replace("\n", "").split(',')
  cursor.execute(insert_row_sql, csv_values)
  # blows up, error msg edited
  # Got error UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'Maga\xf1a, 'invalid continuation byte'), errno is utf-8
```

Comment: Have you tried to print this line directly from the file then decode it? It seems that when you copy the `?` character, it doesn't have the same code as the original.

Comment: How are you reading the CSV file? Are you, for example, using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: No, not using the csv module, just using open and reading each line. Also using python 3

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.